# Is there a universal (regardless of the context) way to say "already"?

Tags: usage, adverbs, word-usage, pragmatics

[JMDict](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html) lists several words for [already](http://tangorin.com/general/already) marked as common:

> もう
>
> 既に
>
> 最早
>
> 早
>
> 先刻
>
> 疾っくに
>
> 兼ねて

Is there any difference between all these "already" words, and is there among them a "universal" one which can be used in any context?

Comment: By 'universal' it sounds to me like you're mostly asking 'is there a perfect Japanese equivalent to the English word "already"'. English 'already' has its own restrictions on usage, and probably doesn't meet your criteria for being 'universal' and 'valid in any context'.

Comment: All three senses of English http://www.dictionary.com/browse/already are very close to each other, they all indicate or imply perfect tense.

Comment: もう is applicable to any of three usages in the link above.

Comment: すでに sounds a bit stiff, but probably technically accomplishes what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be "もう"
I'm not sure how many contexts it could be for the usage of "already" but here's just a few basic examples:

> I already ate = **もう**ご飯食べた
>
> Oh, it's already 12? = あれ、**もう**12時ですか
>
> We're already late = 僕ら、**もう**遅れてるんだ
>
> I already know that = **もう**知ってるんだよ

Hope it helps.